# Is there a way to get a Zestimate of "This home" for January of every year from 2015-2020 using Selenium of Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

From the follwing link I want to be able to scrape the data. However, when I am using Beautiful Soup I could not locate it in the html and Beautiful soup was not working. Furthermore, I thought maybe I can use selenium to scrape this data, but I cannot locate this content either. Do you know how I would use selenium or Beautiful Soup to get the Zestimate of "This home" for January of every year from 2015-2020? Thanks for your help in advance. I am using Python.

https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1954-Sandy-Point-Ln-Mount-Pleasant-SC-29466/10938706_zpid/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it will give the Zestimate for the home.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1954-Sandy-Point-Ln-Mount-Pleasant-SC-29466/10938706_zpid/")

Home_Value = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Home value']")))
action.move_to_element(Home_Value).click().perform()

Zestimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ds-home-values"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/p').text

print(Zestimate)
```

Regarding - "January of every year from 2015-2020?" - You can run the same script manually in Jan to get a latest Zestimate. You can also create a cron job. But I am not sure how to do that.

P.S - After running this script for about 3-4 times i am now facing a CAPTCHA. There is a good explanation available on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254) link

Comment: I am also getting CAPTCHA. Even after reading the link I still am not able to get rid of CAPTCHA. Do you know how to bypass CAPTCHA in this case? @Swaroop Humane

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *Zestimate* i.e. `Zestimate®: $4,232,581` you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1954-Sandy-Point-Ln-Mount-Pleasant-SC-29466/10938706_zpid/')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'For sale')]//following::span[contains(@class, 'ds-dashed-underline') and contains(., 'Zestimate')]//ancestor::span[2]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I want the Zestimate from the graph for the years between 2015- 2020, not the current Zestimate. For example in the image I provided, for January 2015, the number should be $3.2 . Do you know how to get this data?