# Blank screen encountered when using selenium webdriver to navigate Kijiji in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm just trying to make a script that plays with the website kijiji (login, post ads). I did a search but can't seem to find a solution to this. One other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium)
said to use chrome options and a module called fake useragent but I am still getting a [blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV97d.jpg) after clicking the sign in button. Kijiji.ca itself loads up fine but not when signing in. I don't understand why this is happening.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from time import sleep

PATH = executable_path=r"...path to chromedriver.exe..."

options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')


browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=options)

def login():
    browser.get("https://kijiji.ca")
    sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In').click()
    sleep(2)

login()
```

Comment: Seems like re-captcha is reason

Comment: So, any work around?

Comment: I'm not finding any problem. Have you tried without any custom user agent?

Comment: @SAhmed you ran the code?. I did try running the code with and without a custom user agent. It didn't work I think its captcha that stops bot behaviour

Comment: yea I'm really hoping there's some way to work around this.