# How to open a single tab in chromedriver with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium in python 3.8 and write a code to control chromedriver.
The problem is there are too many tabs, almost 10 tabs, are opening when I call driver.get()
They are really useless tabs and I only want to open one single tab with a browser.
What's the problem with my code?
Is there any solution?

Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',['enable-logging'])
chrome_options.add_argument("'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: Delete this line `chrome_options.add_argument("'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'"`. If you have to change the `user-agent`. Refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium

Comment: It perfectly works! Thank you very much :D

Comment: On checking again I see, that your quotes are wrong. It should be `chrome_options.add_argument('"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"')`

Comment: Thank you very much Abhishek, that's the terrible mistake :$

Comment: Glad, could help.