# How to download several CSVs from a website instead of DDOS Cloudflare and 503 Error

Tags: python, r, selenium, cloudflare, http-status-code-503

I have tried to download several CSVs from a website using R and Python, but it doesn't work due to DDOS Cloudflare and 503 Error. Does someone know how to do it?

**Python**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

browser.get('https://spotifycharts.com/regional/br/daily/2020-07-02')

botao = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="header-csv"]')
botao.click()
```

**R**

```
my_file <- read_csv("https://spotifycharts.com/regional/br/daily/2020-07-02/download", skip = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may cause such blocking.
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-Understanding-the-Cloudflare-Browser-Integrity-Check

You can set user-agent to eliminate this possibility

Comment: How to set an user-agent that is able to download the CSV?

Comment: This may help? [python - Way to change Google Chrome user agent in Selenium? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium)

Comment: It still doesn't work with user-agent. New message https://ibb.co/Cnh5Gfs