# Selenium userAgent

Tags: python, selenium

I want to open Google using

- Pythons Selenium
- Google Chrome
- UserAgent (as iPhone)

The following code is working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

But I don't understand following line:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')
```

Why `Mozilla` and `Mac OS X`?

Is there a shorter version with just the standard code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### User Agent

A [User Agent](https://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/work/wiki/Definition_of_User_Agent) is a software which retrieves, renders and facilitates end user interaction with the Web content.

Within the [UserAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1
```

- *`Mozilla/5.0`*: is the general token that says that the browser is Mozilla-compatible. For historical reasons, almost every browser today sends it.
- *`Mac OS X`*: The Chrome (or Chromium/Blink-based engines) user agent string is similar to Firefox. For compatibility, it adds strings like *`KHTML`*, *`like Gecko`* and *`Safari`*. Similarly, older Presto-based Opera releases used *`Mac OS`*.